# pressurizing a space suit

Tags: science-based, physics, space

So was writing a short story about space and I had a random idea.  Could you pressurize  a suit with something other than gas/air?  In theory you could literally put pressure on the person or fill the suit with water if you are a mer person.

Would this be possible? Edit: what I am speaking of if astronauts could  use  a rigid suit to pressurize themselves  giving constant  pressure. OR if the species were merfolk   would water also pressurize a suit well enough

Comment: Hi neo, I’m really curious about this question but think I’m missing some context. Are you asking whether merpeople could develop space travel? Or whether real-life astronauts could replace the air they’re breathing with water? I’ve voted to place your question on hold until you get a chance to [edit] it and provide a little more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's ongoing work to develop a [mechanical counterpressure suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_counterpressure_suit), which uses stretchy materials to squeeze the occupant, with only the helmet needing to be pressurised with some suitable gas or fluid. Helmets can more easily be made rigid and so not have issues with volume changes.

[image: MIT biosuit]

([MIT Biosuit](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/617047main_45s_building_future_spacesuit.pdf))

Filling a suit with water might be tricky, due to its tendency to pool under acceleration. You'd need carefully engineered non-stretchy limb sections and constant-volume joints. In the limit you might actually need to make it out of rigid materials to prevent sloshing, perhaps a little like one of these:

[image: Nasa AX-5 hard suit]

(Nasa AX-5 hard suit)

It *might* be possible to compromise with some sort of gel, but I'm not sure how practical that would be (and getting the suit on and off is going to be quite messy, regardless of whether your native element is air or water!)

It might be easier just to make a miniature one-person spaceship with teleoperation waldoes on it. Von Braun was involved with the design of one of these in the 50s.

[image: von Braun bottle suit]

([von Braun bottle suit](http://cyberneticzoo.com/teleoperators/1954-bottle-suit-wernher-von-braun-walt-disney-american/))

Answer (score 1):

Space suits are pressurized maintain a constant atmosphere for the wearer.  If they weren’t then when they stepped out into vacuum, the suit would expand and the pressure inside would drop, causing problems breathing and the skin to start emitting water vapor as the composition of the gases in the suit tried to equilibrate to the new thermodynamic equilibrium.

If the body was wrapped in some sort of saran wrap/plastic wrap that maintaining constant pressure against the skin, regardless of outside pressure, then this wouldn’t happen.  The head would still need a constant pressure to stop the water of the eyes from turning into vapor and so the wearer could breath.

Obviously this notional design has problems — like maintaining temperature and removing sweat and having nice bendy joints.

Filling a suit with water would work but the extra mass would make working in space very strenuous — overcoming inertia and compensating for high momentum as you move.

A hard suit, one with a rigid outer shell, wouldn’t experience these problems, and the interior could be kept at a constant 1 atm.